# GitHub Packages fails to publish in npm GitHub repo

Tags: github, npm, github-actions, npm-publish

I am new to GitHub Actions and Packages. I am exactly following the [quick start](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/quickstart) to add GitHub Packages.

The `build` job goes fine. I am however getting error on `npm publish` step in the `publish-gpr` job of the pipeline:

```
Run npm publish
npm notice 
npm notice   my-package@1.0.0
npm notice === Tarball Contents === 
npm notice 11.4kB LICENSE                              
npm notice 39B    index.js                             
npm notice 530B   package.json                         
npm notice 670B   .github/workflows/release-package.yml
npm notice === Tarball Details === 
npm notice name:          my-package
npm notice version:       1.0.0                                   
npm notice package size:  4.7 kB                                  
npm notice unpacked size: 12.6 kB                                 
npm notice shasum:        d94d7912f728ae063c5d8d800238e837ebe9688f
npm notice integrity:     sha512-FxsmGChdjckb7[...]vR7NCFxd2xzsA==
npm notice total files:   4                                       
npm notice 
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/my-package - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'gh-packages-test@1.0.0' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2022-10-19T19_58_51_258Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I also find strange that is using `https://registry.npmjs.org/my-package` instead of `https://npm.pkg.github.com/` as specified in the yml.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

I solved. I followed the official doc to fix some issues in the code: https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-npm-registry#authenticating-to-github-packages

e.g. the repository url was wrong in the package.json